# Check if the column value of a row is equal to values in current or other columns for other rows of the same dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` of the following

```
| a| b_1       | b_2       |b_3  |c_1        | c_2       | c_3 |
|--|-----------|-----------|-----|-----------|-----------|-----|
|e1|3295.000000|-775.000000|604.5|3575.000000|-626.000000|604.5|
|e2|3615.000000|-731.000000|604.5|1          |0          |0    |
|e3|3615.000000|-731.000000|604.5|3575.000000|-626.000000|604.5| 
|e2|3615.000000|-731.000000|604.5|1          |0          | 0   | 
|e1|3295.000000|-775.000000|604.5|3575.000000|-626.000000|604.5|
|e4| 0         |0          | 0   |0          |0          | 0   |
```

I want my resultant `dataframe` to look as follows

```
|a | b                              |c                              | d |  
|--|--------------------------------|-------------------------------|------|
|e1| [3295.000000,-775.000000,604.5]|[3575.000000,-626.000000,604.5]|e3| 
|e2| [3615.000000,-731.000000,604.5]|[1, 0, 0]                      |e3| 
|e3| [3615.000000,-731.000000,604.5]|[3575.000000,-626.000000,604.5]|e1, e2|
|e4| [0, 0, 0]                      |[0, 0, 0]                      |None  |
```

Please note that `b` and `c` hold `numpy` arrays of size 3.

The parameters for populating the columns `d` are as follows:

1. If the value in `b`  of the active row is equal to any other
   records in `b` barring itself, then take those records' `a`
   value.
2. If the value in `b`  of the active row is equal to any other
   records in `c` barring itself, then take those records' `a`
   value.
3. If the value in `c`  of the active row is equal to any other
   records in `c` barring itself, then take those records' `a`
   value.
4. None otherwise

Comment: How is generate `b` and `c` columns from first df?

Comment: @jezrael I have changed the data and the table to reflect better the problem I am facing. I generate `b` column like this `df["b"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.array(row['b_1':'b_3']), axis=1)` and `c` column like this `df["c"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.array(row['c_1':'c_3']), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by `a` column:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().copy()
print (df1)

    a           b           c
0  e1   [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, -3]
1  e2  [-1, 2, 3]   [1, 0, 0]
2  e3  [-1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, -3]
5  e4   [0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]
```

Then convert values to numpy arrays, because always same 3 values per columns `b,c`:

```
a = np.array(df1['b'].tolist())
b = np.array(df1['c'].tolist())
```

Compare with broadcasting and exclude same rows by set `False` to diagonal mask:

```
m = (a == a[:, None]).all(axis=2) |  (b == b[:, None]).all(axis=2)
np.fill_diagonal(m, False)
print (m)
[[False False  True False]
 [False False  True False]
 [ True  True False False]
 [False False False False]]
```

Then use [`numpy.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for join values of `df1['a']`, remove last `,` and replace empty string:

```
df1['d'] = np.dot(m, df1['a'] + ',')
df1['d'] = df1['d'].str[:-1].replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
print (df1)
    a           b           c      d
0  e1   [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, -3]     e3
1  e2  [-1, 2, 3]   [1, 0, 0]     e3
2  e3  [-1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, -3]  e1,e2
5  e4   [0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am getting the following error `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ndim'` at the `np.fill_diagonal(m, False)` line

Comment: @Lihka_nonem - What is ouput if remove `np.fill_diagonal(m, False)` ?

Comment: The output for `m` is just a single Boolean `False`.  Should I try the remaining code by commenting out `np.fill_diagonal(m, False)`

Comment: @Lihka_nonem - Are you sure? `m = (a == a[:, None]) |  (b == b[:, None])` should return 2d array.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I am receiving a single boolean. So the arrays in my data were generated like so `df["b"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.array(row['1':'3']), axis=1)`. I did the same thing for `c`. Could this be a reason why this is not working?

Comment: @Lihka_nonem - I add data to answer - it working very well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251791/discussion-between-lihka-nonem-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Lihka_nonem - I found problem, answer is [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75411054/revisions).

Comment: Hi. With your solution + a few edits on my side, I got it working. For some reason, it works when I concatenate the rows into a list instead of a numpy array. I'm not sure why this behaviour exists. I will write an answer with the edits I made to your answer below soon.